# Sort and store a text file?

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to sort and store the following information, which will be read from a txt file:

> ```
> "Michael Jordan, 2/17/1963, basketball, Bulls
> Alex Rodriguez, 7/27/1975, baseball, Yankees
> Emmitt Smith, 3/15/1969, football, Cowboys"
> ```

Here is the code I have thus far:

```
def main():
    athletes = []
    file = input("Please enter a file name: ")
    fn = open(file,mode='r')
```

I know I need to fill the array, but how would I go about splitting the txt file since there are both spaces and commas? I want the array to hold `[first name, last name, birthday, sport, team]`

Comment: What do you need to sort by?

Comment: FWIW, [] is a list, not an array.  In Python, an array is something different.

Comment: I want the list to hold the first name, last name, birthdate, sport,and team name

Comment: @dstromberg thanks for pointing that out. I need to re phrase

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer:

**`string.split()`**

```
for line in fn:
    name, dob, sport, team = line.split(', ')
```

More complicated answer:

Use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module. It's a bit more complicated to start out with, but will get you further.

Comment: He also needs to split `name` by space to get first name and last name.

Comment: I inserted that line and got the following error.

    ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Is there a way I could use a list with this, or no?

Comment: Then apparently you have a line with no comma on it. Try adding this: `print('line: <{}>'.format(line))` above the `.split()` line. Then you'll be able to see the value of the line that's causing your error.

Comment: the spacing was off in the text file. I fixed the spacing and ran it again, but got the following error instead: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)

Comment: @anana any suggestions? I do need to split by space to get first name and last name in addition to every other attribute

Comment: on the next line: `first_name, last_name = name.split(None, 1)` (If you have something like `Rip Van Winkle`)

Comment: i figured it out, but can't answer my question for a few more hours. will post the solution then...thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend numpy!

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.genfromtxt('my_file.txt', dtype='str', delimiter=',')
```

Comment: We haven't been introduced to numpy

Comment: I can only recommend it, it is one of the most popular python scistack packages. You can simply get it via pip

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I filled the list, then split name.

```
for line in fn:
   x = line.split(', ')
   fullName = x[0]
   birthday = x[1]
   sport = x[2]
   team = x[3]

   fullNameSplit = fullName.split(" ")
   firstName = fullNameSplit[0]
   lastName = fullNameSplit[1]
```